# jersey client 3, spring boot 3, jackson 2.15. @JsonProperty not working after updating to spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jersey-client

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class SomeResponseDTO {

  @JsonProperty("refresh_token")
  private String refreshToken;

  @JsonProperty("expires_in")
  private int expiresIn;

  @JsonProperty("scope")
  public String scope;
}
```

`@JsonProperty` doesn't work anymore for the first 2 properties having underscore in the property names, worrks for scope..after updating to spring boot 3, and using jersey client 3 ..

SomeResponseDTO someResponseDTO = response.readEntity(SomeResponseDTO.class);

tried changing jackson versions.

Comment: Are you having exceptions? Are you not deserializing data that is actually in the json?

Comment: registering     ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
    configuration.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class); should do the serialization and deserialization.

Comment: import com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;

Comment: Apparently, spring boot 3 ships with Jackson 2.15.2 and jersey 3.1.3 , and in the above scenario it doesn't work. 

It was solved by putting @JsonbProperty from jakarta.json.bind-api

Comment: Also was solved by using configuration.register(JacksonFeature.class) from jersey client, instead of using JacksonJsonProvider. then there was no need of @JsonbProperty also